# Rust Webview JavaScript interface

Tags: rust

I am a newbie in Rust development.

I know that Android apps can expose JavaScript interface APIs to web plugins (run inside a Webview).

I would like to ask whether "Can Rust native apps expose JavaScript interface APIs to web plugins (run inside a webkit2gtk::Webview)" ?

If it's possible, please share some code snippets.

Currently, I must use a Webservice to export RESTful APIs to web plugins. But ideally, we find some solutions that are similar with Android Webview JavaScriptInterface.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am developing a Web plug-in of Rust native app (Plug-in will be loaded into a webkit2gtk::Webview instance of native Rustapp). My plug-in must `fetch` ( via GET/POST/PUT/DELETE requests) data from remote servers. My Web plug-in could not use default JavaScript `fetch` due to blocking by CORS errors. Therefore, I must find a way to call `fetch` handlers from Rust native app.